# Password reset django-allauth and django-rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I cannot wrap my head around this problem. Read a lot of solutions but cannot seem to find the correct combination that works for me.

I want to initiate a users password reset flow from within my (android/iOS) app.
I think I need `django-rest-auth` for this to expose an API endpoint something like this:

```
from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetView

urlpatterns = [
    path('password/reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset'),
]
```

Now posting to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset/` with a JSON payload of `{ "email": "test1@test.com" }` gives an error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found.`

Now, I'm strugeling with the next part. I found that password_reset_confirm is defined in `django.contrib.auth` but I do not want to expose the `admin-like` interface to the user.

I'd like to use the `allauth PasswordResetFromKeyView`.

So, defining `password_reset_confirm` as:

```
    path('password/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         PasswordResetFromKeyView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_confirm'
         ),
```

Works. An email is send containing a reset URL. But now, following that URL I'm getting another error: `PasswordResetFromKeyView.dispatch() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'uidb36' and 'key'`

Ok, obvious, changed the `password_reset_confirm` path arguments from `<uidb64>` and `<token>` to `<uidb36>` and `<key>`.
Than the error moves to `password_reset_email.html` because of the arguments in
`{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` 
Ok, also changed that to `uidb32=uid` `and key=token` results in a HTML page displaying "BAD TOKEN".

Now, I'm completely at a loss.
How to configure django-allauth and django-rest-auth so that I can do a rest request to send the email containing a valid URL which the user can use to change his/her password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I just saw django-allauth is no longer maintained and that you should switch to: dj-rest-auth. Now the process starts all over again...

Ok, the following works, posting for reference because I have lost an awful lot of time on this.

Pipfile:

```
[packages]
django = "~=3.0"
django-allauth = "0.50.0"
django-rest-auth = "0.9.5"
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path

# Register
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView, VerifyEmailView

# Password reset
from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    re_path(r'^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$',
            ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),

    path('user/register/',
         RegisterView.as_view(),
         name='rest_register'
         ),
    path('user/verify-email/',
         VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
         name='rest_verify_email'
         ),

    # Password reset
    path('user/password/reset/',
         PasswordResetView.as_view(),
         name='rest_password_reset'
         ),

    path('user/password/reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

I'm able to post to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/password/reset/` with a JSON payload of `{ "email": "test1@test.com" }`.

A Email is generated with an reset URL, clicking this URL brings the user to the browsable API page of Django:

[image: rest_reset_password]

However, this page is not intended to be exposed to the user. So my next question on S.O. is: [How to create a custom page for the user to reset his/her password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71815707/customize-django-allauth-django-rest-auth-password-reset-confirm)

Comment: so basically what you need to do is build a page which is available under the 'password_reset_confirm' view. On this page, you will send the contents via api to the PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view().

You URL configuration is wrong. The dj_rest_auth is:

path('password/reset/confirm/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset_confirm') --> this is the API url your new page should be sending the url to
The 'password_reset_confirm' url needs to be a new form which then send the results to the 'rest_password_reset_confirm'. This is why it is not defined.

Comment: In the package AllAuth, it is the page: account/password_reset_from_key.html

Comment: one more solution found here:
https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/302
basically you need to overwrite the Serializer to point to the correct URL

Comment: DIJ did you find the solution for this?