# How to connect django allauth socials to frontend?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I managed to setup allauth for github authentication but I dont know how to connect it properly to my frontend so I can login through frontend and fetch needed data for displayment.

I tried many things. Currently I have managed to make it so when I login, I get redirected to a json page full of login data needed for frontend but still cant find a proper way to connect it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check my reply on a similar question here, I am mentioning how to connect it with frontend as well: [Customize django-allauth / django-rest-auth Password Reset Confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71815707/customize-django-allauth-django-rest-auth-password-reset-confirm/77984330#77984330)

For Google authentication and React I am using @react-oauth/google. It normally opens the Google's pop up to choose your gmail to authenticate etc. For Github, I don't remember how it is working, so check the official Github documentation for an api on that.